# JAAS and web service authorization : get logged user

Tags: java, rest, ejb, jaas

I've a JSF application that do login via JAAS.
It works fine.

Now, my page calls a REST web service. I need to know who did the request.

In the request's header I have:

```
Cookie = JSESSIONID=XBHZuYnzgkGyQSR8kBLNSks_s7nuXAMli7Gp-9Mn.dlicitra; _ga=GA1.1.1590792307.1560863707
```

The web service is implemented in a Stateless EJB. The method is:

```
@Path(value = "myservice/{id}")
@GET
@Produces(value = "application/json")
public List<Records> getServices(
        @HeaderParam(value = "Cookie") String cookie,
        @PathParam(value = "id") Long id){
    return ... ;
}
```

How can I get the logged user from the *cookie* string?

Comment: Have you tried injecting `@Context SecurityContext` in your EJB?

Comment: thank you @perissf, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment, instead of mangling with parsing or decoding the cookie's SessionId, I'd go with the Java EE's security API built-in solution of injecting the [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) into the EJB, and getting the userPrincipal from it:

```
@Context
private SecurityContext securityContext;
```

And in your method:

```
Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
```

See also:

[Baeldung's post on Java EE 8 Security API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-8-security)